# i have a problem in pentaho bi server dynamic row

Tags: pentaho, business-intelligence, dynamicquery, pentaho-cde, pentaho-report-designer

im trying to set the select of the  sql query of pentaho bi server dynamic but it didn't work here is my code :
select SELECT
CASE ${param}
WHEN 'productLine' THEN productLine
WHEN 'productVendor' THEN productVendor
ELSE productLine
END AS groupByColumn, Sum(quantityInStock) as totalQuantity
from products
group by productLine
[this is what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stsbm.png)
[and here is my param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bex4F.png)

i tried to change it without params it worked but every time i add param it don't work